# GSON to JSON - multiple objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using GSON and would like to have it convert multiple lists to JSON - that will be one object - is there any way to do this without manipulating the lists or using a new data structure?

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.populate();
list2.populate(); 

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
gson.toJson(list1, list2);// ----> THIS IS WHAT I WANT
```

I want the result to be something like this - pseudocode JSON
first result of first list to correlate with first result of second list

```
{
  list1[element1]: list2[element1], 
  list1[element2]: list2[element2],
  list1[element3]:  list2[element3].....
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you expect the resulting JSON to look like?

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Please post a valid JSON example.

Comment: I updated the question to include the desired result - thanks!

Comment: JSON objects contains name-value pairs. It looks like you want a JSON array of zipped values from both lists.

Comment: Are you asking how to zip two lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with modification of the list in memory?

```
list1.populate();
list2.populate(); 
list1.addAll(list2); 

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
gson.toJson(list1);
```

Obviously populate isn't a method of lists, but you can only convert single objects to JSON

If order is at all important, you have to find a way to populate a singular list containing the data in the order you need